# SpringLayout NotSerializableException - but not using SpringLayout?

Tags: notserializableexception, springlayout

While attempting to save data via a FileOutputStream and ObjectOutputStream, I will get an intermittent error for a SpringLayout NotSerializableException, however I do not use SpringLayout in any of my code. I only use two external JARs (iTextPDF and JDatePicker), which are not part of the data that is attempting to be saved. The line that generates it from my code is "at com.coding.doernerd.SaveFile.save(SaveFile.java:47)". I'm at my wits end trying to track down this bug and have no where left to go. Thanks in advance!

```
java.io.NotSerializableException: javax.swing.SpringLayout
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.access$300(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream$PutFieldImpl.writeFields(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeFields(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.writeObject(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor15.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeWriteObject(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeArray(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.access$300(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream$PutFieldImpl.writeFields(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeFields(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.writeObject(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor15.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeWriteObject(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeArray(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.access$300(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream$PutFieldImpl.writeFields(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeFields(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.writeObject(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor15.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeWriteObject(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeArray(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.access$300(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream$PutFieldImpl.writeFields(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeFields(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.writeObject(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor15.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeWriteObject(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeArray(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.access$300(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream$PutFieldImpl.writeFields(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeFields(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.writeObject(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor15.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeWriteObject(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeArray(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.access$300(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream$PutFieldImpl.writeFields(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeFields(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.writeObject(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor15.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeWriteObject(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeArray(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.access$300(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream$PutFieldImpl.writeFields(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeFields(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.writeObject(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor15.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeWriteObject(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeArray(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.access$300(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream$PutFieldImpl.writeFields(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeFields(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.writeObject(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor15.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeWriteObject(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Window.writeObject(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor33.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeWriteObject(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.save(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Window.writeObject(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor33.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeWriteObject(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(Unknown Source)
at java.util.ArrayList.writeObject(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor30.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeWriteObject(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(Unknown Source)
*** at com.coding.doernerd.SaveFile.save(SaveFile.java:47) ***
*** at com.coding.doernerd.FAST.saveFile(FAST.java:11453) ***
*** at com.coding.doernerd.FAST$118.actionPerformed(FAST.java:4944) ***
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.doClick(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicMenuItemUI.doClick(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicMenuItemUI$Handler.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Here's the code that is generating the error. Most of the time it works fine. I haven't been able to exactly recreate the issue that generates the error, as it changes every time. The data type that's trying to be saved is ArrayList, that is the top-level structure that everything else in my program utilizes/references - but no SpringLayout implementations.

```
public class SaveFile {
private String filename;
private Object[] object;

public SaveFile(String filename, Object[] object) {
    this.filename = filename;
    this.object = object;
}

public String getFilename() {
    return filename;
}

public Object[] getObject() {
    return object;
}

public boolean save() {
    File checkReadOnly = new File(filename);
    if (checkReadOnly.exists() && !checkReadOnly.canWrite()) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "'" + checkReadOnly.getName() + "' is read only.", "Unable to Save", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        return false;
    }
    
    String workingFilename = filename.substring(0, filename.length() - 4) + "_saving" + filename.substring(filename.length() - 4);      
    FileOutputStream tempOutput = null;
    ObjectOutputStream tempFile = null;
    int errorIndex = 0;
    try {
        tempOutput = new FileOutputStream(new File(workingFilename));
        tempFile = new ObjectOutputStream(tempOutput);
        for (int i = 0; i < object.length; i++) {
            errorIndex = i;
            tempFile.writeObject(object[i]);
        }
        tempFile.close();
        tempOutput.close();
        File file = new File(workingFilename);
        file.delete();
        
        FileOutputStream output;
        ObjectOutputStream saveFile;
        output = new FileOutputStream(new File(filename));
        saveFile = new ObjectOutputStream(output);
        for (int i = 0; i < object.length; i++) {
            saveFile.writeObject(object[i]);
        }
        saveFile.close();
        output.close();
        
        return true;
    } catch (Exception  e) {
        File file = new File(workingFilename);
        if (file.exists()) file.delete();
        
        String errorComponent = "";
        switch (errorIndex) {
        case 0:
            errorComponent = "The reference ID component";
            break;
        case 1:
            errorComponent = "The classification component";
            break;
        case 2:
            errorComponent = "The list of squadrons";
            break;
        case 3:
            errorComponent = "The list of daily flight information";
            break;
        case 4:
            errorComponent = "The list of solar/lunar almanac prediction data";
            break;
        case 5:
            errorComponent = "The list of marker data";
            break;
        }
        
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, errorComponent + " generated an error during save attempt.", "Unable to Save", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        
        FAST.logError(e);
    }
    
    try {
        if (tempFile != null) tempFile.close();
        if (tempOutput != null) tempOutput.close();
    } catch (Exception  e) {}
    
    return false;
}
```

}